# Syntax and Logic errors C#

Tags: c#, union, hashset

I am having trouble debugging my code. I found this code in a book example in an incomplete form and containing syntax error and logical errors and I tried my best to debug it and correct these errors. But unfortunately I could not figure out errors even using the debugger. What changes should I need to do in order to correct this code?

```
namespace Exercise_9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //make some sets
            //Note, this is where I make the correction within the code. 
            //Originally, this was written as Set A = new Set(); and
            // Set B = new Set(); 

            //Here is the correction by assigning the set variable 
            Set A = new Set();
            Set B = new Set();

            //put some stuff in the sets
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                A.addElement(r.Next(4));
                B.addElement(r.Next(12));
            }

            //display each set and the union
            Console.WriteLine("A: " + A);
            Console.WriteLine("B: " + B);
            Console.WriteLine("A union B: " + A.union(B)); //note, I believe this isnt a proper notation. 

            //display original sets (should be unchanged)
            Console.WriteLine("After union operation");
            Console.WriteLine("A: " + A);
            Console.WriteLine("B: " + B);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: your question not clear to me what you wanna do exactly ? wanna catch exceptions raised ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: is it even compiling ? `int A = new Set(A);` ?

Comment: Please add code of your Set class

Comment: In adding the code, what must I change in my Set class?

Comment: Halil Ibrahim- I want to detect all the errors in my code so I can fix them and see the changes made to have my program to work efficiently.

Comment: I suppose the Bug you are asked to find is in the Set class and not in this Main method. Probably, the union method incorrectly modifies the set.

Answer (score 0):

After looking your code and comments, I think that you want to utilize HashSet datastructure of C#. In that case, you may try doing something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Exercise_9
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        HashSet<int> A = new HashSet<int>();
        HashSet<int> B = new HashSet<int>();

        //put some stuff in the sets
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            A.Add(r.Next(4));
            B.Add(r.Next(12));
        }

        //display each set and the union
        Console.WriteLine("Values in A are: ");
        foreach (var value in A) {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Values in B are: ");
        foreach (var value in B) {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        HashSet<int> C = A;
        // storing union in set C using UnionWith
        C.UnionWith(B);

        Console.WriteLine("Values in union set - C are: ");
        foreach (var value in C) {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After union operation");

        Console.WriteLine("Values in A are: ");
        foreach (var value in A) {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Values in B are: ");
        foreach (var value in B) {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
 }
```